# Can 遅く mean 'slowly'?

Tags: usage

From my book,

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

However, [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E9%81%85%E3%81%8F) says that 遅く can mean 'slowly,' but I can't find an example for that meaning in the same source.

In this [thread](https://it.hinative.com/questions/17018740), answerers agree that 遅く can be used to mean 'slowly.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

遅く can mean *slowly*, but ゆっくり is almost always preferred in non-technical contexts. もっと遅く食べた方がいいよ and 彼は遅く走る are not completely wrong but do sound fairly unnatural to me.

遅く meaning *slowly* may be naturally used in scientific contexts because ゆっくり can have unwanted nuances like "relaxed; leisurely". For example, saying 物体が光の速度に近づくと時間が遅く流れる referring to the theory of relativity looks natural to me.